# Converting Timestamp as String to Date in android

Tags: android, timestamp

I am getting Timestamp value as 1291204449 from server so I extracted the value by
implementing handler.

Now I want to convert timestamp value  to date.(But the problem is in my activity I stored this value in a string variable because handler returning in string format).

Answer (score 10):

Just use the [Time](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) class. Try something similar to this.

```
Time time = new Time();
time.set(Long.valueOf(yourTimeString));
```

If you really need a [Date](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) object just try this.

```
Date date = new Date(Long.parse(yourTimeString));
```

Comment: Long.parseLong(yourTimeString)

Answer (score 3):

I have a function for converting timestamps in String Format:

```
public static String create_datestring(String timestring){
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(timestring));
    timestring = add_string(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)),"0",2,0) + "." +  add_string(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1),"0",2,0) + "." + String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)) + " " + add_string(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)),"0",2,0) + ":" + add_string(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)),"0",2,0);
    return timestring;
}
```

Comment: Watch out when using the `Calender` class as it is slower than the `Time` class. Also concatenating a string that way is not very efficient. Try to use a `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: @2red13 what is the `add_string` function? I agree with @Octavian Damiean, maybe a StringBuilder would be more efficient?