# unix timestamp to datetime in android

Tags: android, datetime, simpledateformat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting Timestamp as String to Date in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375982/converting-timestamp-as-string-to-date-in-android)

My server is returning a timestamp 1322400600 in String, In my android application, i need to convert it like Nov 27, 2011 07:00am. I don't know how to do this please help me out.

-
Thanks
AvMishra

**Solutions:**

I used following code to get the desired value

```
long dv = Long.valueOf(timestamp_in_string)*1000;// its need to be in milisecond
Date df = new java.util.Date(dv);
String vv = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd, yyyy hh:mma").format(df);
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `new java.util.Date(Long.parseLong(timeInMillis))`. With this `Date` object there are several ways to extract the date in your desired `String` format, the simplest way using `Date.toString()`. Alternatively, and more appropriately you can use a `SimpleDateFormat` with the exact pattern you want.

Comment: thanks Che Jami! for your quick response.

Comment: I used following code to get the desired value

    long dv = Long.valueOf(timestamp_in_string)*1000;// its need to be in milisecond
    Date df = new java.util.Date(dv);
    String vv = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd, yyyy h:ma").format(df);

Answer (score 6):

This should get you the same time format:

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```