# To get Date and time from Timestamp Android

Tags: android, timestamp

I want to get time and date separately from timestamp.Please help me in these. My example of timestamp is 1378798459.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 39, accepted):

//Try the following

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(YOUR TIMESTAMP VALUE)));
txtDate.setText(dateString);
```

//You can put your needed format here:

`SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YOUR REQUIRED FORMAT");`

Comment: For the various date formats see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55645964/3904109

Comment: Multiply timestamp value with 1000 to get correct result ''''SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(YOUR TIMESTAMP VALUE)*1000));
txtDate.setText(dateString);'''

Answer (score 13):

Improving upon the answer given by Pratik Dasa

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Here you can get various formats using the following syntax.  You can play around with it by deleting or adding terms given below in the syntax.

```
Date and Time Pattern                Result
-----------------------------        ---------------------------------
"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z"       2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT
"EEE, MMM d, ''yy"                   Wed, Jul 4, '01
"h:mm a"                             12:08 PM
"hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz"              12 o'clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time
"K:mm a, z"                          0:08 PM, PDT
"yyyyy.MMMMM.dd GGG hh:mm aaa"       02001.July.04 AD 12:08 PM
"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"         Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700
"yyMMddHHmmssZ"                      010704120856-0700
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"         2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"       2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00
"YYYY-'W'ww-u"                       2001-W27-3
```

Answer (score 7):

```
String time = DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, 1378798459, DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME);
String date =  DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, 1378798459, DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date date = cal.getTime();
mHour = date.getHours();
mMinute = date.getMinutes();
```

Comment: `date.getHours()` and `date.getMinutes()` are deprecated now. :(

Answer (score 2):

Only that:

```
long timestampString =  Long.parseLong("yourString");
String value = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").
    format(new java.util.Date(timestampString * 1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long dv = Long.valueOf(timestamp_in_string)*1000;// its need to be in milisecond
Date df = new java.util.Date(dv);
String vv = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd, yyyy hh:mma").format(df);
```

[From here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034956/unix-timestamp-to-datetime-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
int day, month, year;
                int second, minute, hour;
                GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();

                day = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                month = date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                year = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                second = date.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                minute = date.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                hour = date.get(Calendar.HOUR);

               String   data  =(hour+ ':'+  ""+minute+ ':'+"" +second+"" +""+"" +day+"" +"/" +(month+1)+"" +"/"+ +year);



Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Time stamp:"+data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String ts = tsLong.toString();

    long millisecond = Long.parseLong(ts);
    datetimeString = DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss a", new Date(millisecond)).toString();
    timeString = datetimeString.substring(11);
    dateString = datetimeString.substring(0,10);
    String t2 = datetimeString.substring(20,21);
```

The datetimeString contains the Date Time AM/PM data
timeString will give you the substring which contains the time only and the dateString is substring for date
The String t2 will give you whether it is AM or PM in the clock

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();

when.setText(dateFormat.format(new Date(timestamp * 1000)));
```

The timestamp is multiplied by 1000 for converting the seconds into milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are great and they mainly focus on converting the `unix timestamp` to `milliseconds` first, which is correct.

I struggled to apply that because I must use `1000L` in the conversion (instead of `1000` only). Here's my working code with time zone conversion

```
// Set TimeZone
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy h:mm a", Locale.US);
dateFormat.setTimeZone(getDeviceTimeZone());
// Set time
Date date = new Date(timestamp * 1000L);
return dateFormat.format(date);
```

For Android API 26 and above, you can just do

```
return Instant.ofEpochSecond( timestamp )
        .atZone(ZoneId.of( timezone ))
        .toLocalDateTime()
        .toString();
```

Comment: Only this answer is relevant in 2021

Comment: `1000L` We must have to use `L`

Answer (score 0):

**The very best way to get day and date from the timestamp is that:**

```
java.util.Date dayAndDate = new java.util.Date( (long) yourTimeStamp * 1000);
```

**// object coming as like: Tue Feb 09**

```
String day = dayAndDate.toString().split(" ")[0];

String month = dayAndDate.toString().split(" ")[1];

String date = dayAndDate.toString().split(" ")[2];
```

**I hope you will like my approach, if you have liked it, don't forget to give it an upvote, so that others will consider it.**

Comment: This is probably the very worst way. Consider this answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64382147/4751720

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use time like in a WhatsApp message, You can use this method,

```
public static String millisToDateChat(long time) {

        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long defe = currentTime - time;
        long  time_in;

        if(time!=0){   
            time_in = time;   
        }else{
            time_in = currentTime;
            defe = 0;
        }

        int s = (int)defe/1000;
        int m = (int)defe/(1000*60);
        int h = (int)defe/(1000*60*60);
        int d = (int)defe/(1000*60*60*24);
        int w = (int)defe/(1000*60*60*24*7);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(time_in);
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String formattedDate=(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")).format(date);
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String formattedYear=(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, ''yy")).format(date);
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String formattedm=(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d")).format(date);

        if(d>365) {
            return formattedYear;
        }else if(s>172000){
            return formattedm;
        }else if(s>86400) {
            return "Yest.";
        }else{
            return formattedDate;
        }
    }
```